# Several questions about the exercises in Artin's "Algebra"

Tags: group-theory

The exercises are from the chapter 9 "Linear groups"

- For (4.1): Let $W$ be the space of real skew-symmetric 3 x 3 matrices. Describe the orbits for the operation $P\ast A=PAP^t$ of $SO_3$ on $W$.

(Do we have any spectral theory related to this problems? Do I miss any one of them?)

- For (4.8b): Let $W$ be the real vector space of Hermitian 2 x 2 matrices. Prove that the function $\langle A,A'\rangle =\det(A+A')-\det(A)-\det(A')$ is a bilinear form on $W$, and that its signature is $(3,1)$.

(Indeed, I have calculated the signature should be $(1,3)$, so I'm thing about the question missed a negetive sign in the bilinear form i.e. it should be $\langle A,A'\rangle =-[\det(A+A')-\det(A)-\det(A')]$, then we can have signature $(3,1)$, am I right or not?)

- For (5.9): Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to GL_n$ be a one-parameter group. Prove that $\ker(\phi)$ is either trivial, or an infinite cyclic group, or the whole group.

(While I can show that those three cases exist but so far have not yet figured out only those three cases happen.)

Any ideas or hints are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Note the space $W$ of $3 \times 3$ real antisymmetric matrices can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^3$ by
  $$v = \begin{bmatrix}
  a \\ b \\ c \\
  \end{bmatrix} \mapsto
  A_v= \begin{bmatrix} 
  0 & -a_3 & a_2 \\ 
  a_3 & 0 & -a_1 \\ 
  -a_2 & a_1 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix}$$
  so that $A_v w = v \times w$. What action of $SO(3)$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ do we get by making this identification?
- I'm not sure about the second question, since different people use different conventions to define the signature of a quadratic form.
- For the last one, first prove that every nontrivial subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ is either dense or infinite cyclic. So, provided $\phi$ is continuous so that $\ker \phi$ is a closed subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$, we  can only have $\ker(\phi)$ be trivial, everything, or infinite cyclic. I assume your $\phi$ must be continuous, right? Otherwise you could have some crazy non measurable map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, with a similarly crazy kernel (say by thinking of $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, and choosing a projection onto $\mathbb{Q})$, and then turn this into a map $\mathbb{R} \to GL(n\mathbb{R})$ by using the exponential map.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks for ur hints, now I know how to do the first and third questions. For 4.8b, in my definition, signature (3,1) means the matrix of the symmetric form is a diagonal matrix such that the diagonal entries are 1,1,1,-1

Answer (score 0):

for **4.8(b)**

$A\sim\begin{pmatrix} λ_1 & \\ & λ_2 \end{pmatrix}$

$A^{'}\sim\begin{pmatrix} λ_2^{'} & \\ & λ_1^{'} \end{pmatrix}$

$\mathbb{F}^{2×2}\cong\mathbb{F}^4$

the form on $W$ is nondegenarated

$I_{p,m,z}$, $z=0$

$\begin{pmatrix} λ_1 & 0 & λ_2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} I_{p,m} \begin{pmatrix} λ_2^{'} \\ 0 \\ λ_1^{'} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = λ_{1}λ_2^{'}+λ_1^{'}λ_2 = \left\langle A,A^{'}\right\rangle $

if $(p,m)=(0,4)$, we'll at most get $-λ_{1}λ_2^{'}-λ_1^{'}λ_2$

if $(p,m)=(1,3)$ or $(2,2)$, we'll at most get $λ_{1}λ_2^{'}-λ_1^{'}λ_2$ or $-λ_{1}λ_2^{'}+λ_1^{'}λ_2$

if $(p,m)=(4,0)$, the form $\left\langle A,A^{'}\right\rangle$ is equivalent to the dot product

but ${\forall}A≠0$, det$A=0$, we have, $\left\langle A,A\right\rangle=2$det$A=0$

it's a contradiction to the dot product

so $(p,m)=(3,1)$

Comment: $λ_1$, $λ_2$ are eigenvalues, so there may be a structure from $\mathbb{F}^{2×2}$ to $\mathbb{F}^4$ to let $p≠2$, I don't exactly know, just for reference only, and 抛砖引玉